# Error 500 in Django production, can't see the error

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

i'm using django and wsgi. 
When i run the command runserver with DEBUG = True or False everything it's fine but when i create the daemon to run my app i got the page with 500 error, in the apache's logs i got the error 500 but i can't see the error even if the DEBUG is in True, i think it's problem with apache(2.4.41) and wsgi
This is the config file to create the daemon

```
Alias /static /home/(user)/(domain)/static

<ifmodule mod_wsgi.c>
    WSGIDaemonProcess ic user=(user) group=(user) processes=1 threads=2 python-path=/home/(user)/(domain):/home/(user)/.venv/ic
</ifmodule>
WSGIProcessGroup ic
WSGIApplicationGroup ic
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/(user)/(domain)/ic/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization on

<Directory /home/(user)/(domain)/ic/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
LogLevel debug
Errorlog /var/log/apache2/domlogs/(domain)_error
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domlogs/(domain)_custom combined
```

In the errorlog show this (the venv was created)

```
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.138254 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] ssl_util_stapling.c(874): AH01956: stapling_cb: setting response
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.316201 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23440] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 0 (server (url):443)
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.316509 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23440] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.316520 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23440] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.317397 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23440] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.317408 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9308:tid 47752169862912] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:23440] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.328015 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 9302:tid 47752171964160] mod_wsgi (pid=9302): Create interpreter 'ic'.
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.341454 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 9302:tid 47752171964160] mod_wsgi (pid=9302): Adding '/home/(user)/(domain)' to path.
[Sat Jan 11 10:24:54.341632 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 9302:tid 47752171964160] mod_wsgi (pid=9302): Adding '/home/(user)/.venv/ic' to path.
```

The wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ic.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

"Help me, Stackoverflow. You're my only hope."

Comment: If the wsgi application is being created then it would suggest the error is happening later on, in the request. You'll need to configure [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) so that you can check what errors are being reported by Django.

Comment: I put the logging info level DEBUG and the file was created but empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i was watching another error log, my problem was in the virtualenv